# Apache default error page

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I have a development server and I would like to configure Apache so that when a 500 http code is generated it will display the error directly in the response (i.e. what would be printed to `/var/log/httpd/error_log` is displayed to the user).

However, I cannot figure out where this directive is.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the directive you are looking for is `ErrorDocument` (documented [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument)).  For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...

    ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
</VirtualHost>
```

On a second read-through of your question it appears you may be asking for Apache to display the error directly in the browser (i.e. what would appear in /var/log/httpd/error_log).  Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi. Your second guess is the one I am interested in. I want it to print the error to the browser, not a custom error page. Thanks

Comment: This isn't seemingly easy as it represents a complex change in how Apache normally handles these errors.  I can appreciate how frustrating it can be to not get immediate assistance from volunteers during their work day...

Comment: @Thomas As far as I'm aware there's no way to do this without putting it together yourself with dynamic code in a custom 500 handler page.  I can't blame Apache for not building it in, either - having this on a production web server would be reckless information disclosure, while using it for debugging seems pointless since the error log is easily `tail`-able.

Answer (score 2):

Set up Apache to use server-side includes (.shtml files) and configure a custom error page as above (though naturally pointing to an .shtml file), and in that custom error page use something like this:

```
<p>The requested page, <code>
<!--#echo var="REQUEST_URI" --></code>,
 does not work properly.</p>

<p>Click <a href='<!--#echo var="HTTP_REFERER" -->'>here</a> to return from whence you came.</p>

<fieldset>
<legend>Error Message</legend>
<xmp>
<!--#echo var="REDIRECT_ERROR_NOTES" -->
</xmp>
</fieldset>

<!--
<!--#echo var="HTTP_USER_AGENT" -->
<!--#echo var="REDIRECT_STATUS" -->
-->
```